# Bug in userauth component cakephp 2.5.5

Tags: php, ajax, cakephp

I'm using Usermgmt plugin. for the login process I make a request with ajax. This works fine on localhost but not on the hosting.
In hosting the function login works except the call " $this->UserAuth->login($user)"

**Funtion login in Userscontroller.php**

```
public function login($type=0,$subtype=0) {

    $this->layout = 'plantilla';
    if ($this->request -> isPost()) {
        if($this->User->LoginValidate()) {
            $email  = $this->data['User']['email'];
            $password = $this->data['User']['password'];
            $user = $this->User->findByUsername($email);
            if (empty($user)) {
                $user = $this->User->findByEmail($email);
                if (empty($user)) {
                    //$this->Session->setFlash(__('Usuario y/o contraseña incorrecto.'));
                    echo "Usuario y/o contraseña incorrecto";
                    exit();
                }
            }
            // check for inactive account
            if ($user['User']['id'] != 1 and $user['User']['active']==0) {
                //$this->Session->setFlash(__('Su registro no ha sido confirmado por favor verifique su correo electrónico o contacte al administrador'));
                echo "Su registro no ha sido confirmado por favor verifique su correo electrónico o contacte al administrador";
                exit();
            }

            $hashed = $this->UserAuth->makePassword($password);
            if ($user['User']['password'] === $hashed) {

             $this->UserAuth->login($user);

                $remember = (!empty($this->data['User']['remember']));
                if ($remember) {
                    $this->UserAuth->persist('2 weeks');
                }
                $OriginAfterLogin=$this->Session->read('Usermgmt.OriginAfterLogin');
                $this->Session->delete('Usermgmt.OriginAfterLogin');
                $rol = $this->User->find('all',array('conditions' => array('email' => $email)));
                if($rol['0']['User']['user_group_id']==1){
                    $redirect = "/projects";//(!empty($OriginAfterLogin)) ? $OriginAfterLogin : loginRedirectUrl;
                    //$this->redirect($redirect);
                    echo 1;
                    exit();
                }
                if($this->data['User']['page'] == "projects"){
                    echo 2;
                    exit();
                }

                else {
                    $redirect = "/";
                    //$this->redirect($redirect);
                    echo 0;
                    exit();
                }
            } else {
                //$this->Session->setFlash(__('Usuario y/o contraseña incorrecto.'));
                echo "Usuario y/o contraseña incorrecto.";
                exit();
            }
        }else{
            $this->User->set($this->data);
            //$this->Session->setFlash(__('Formulario Vacío.'));
            echo "Formulario Vacío";
            exit();
        }
    }
    $conditions=$subtype!=0?array('Project.project_subtype_id'=>$subtype):array('Project.project_type_id'=>$type);
    $this->set('parents_type', $this->ProjectType->find('all', array('conditions' => array('ProjectType.parent_id' => 0))));
    $this->set('projects', $this->Project->find('all',array('conditions'=>$conditions)));

}
```

**Peticion con ajax**

```
$(function() {
    //Actions to submit login modal
   $('#user-login').submit(function() {

  var ser = $('#user-login').serialize();

    $.ajax({
      async: true,    
     type: 'POST',

     url: '<?php echo $this->webroot?>usermgmt/users/login',
     data: ser,
             success: function(msg){

     if(msg == 1){ window.location = '<?php echo $this->webroot?>projects';}
        else if(msg == 2){ location.reload(true);}
        else if(msg == 0){ window.location ='<?php echo $this->webroot?>';}
        else {$("#error-login").html("<div class='alert alert-danger'>"+msg+"</div>");}

        //alert(msg);

         },
 error: function(msg){
 alert("Error");
 }
   });
     return false;
 });
```

Comment: Contact the author of the plugin. But honestly, what I've seen so far from this plugin, I wouldn't recommend to use it any way for multiple reasons.

Comment: @burzum Any chance that the problem is not the plugin

Comment: "`This works fine on localhost but not on the hosting.`" is nothing anyone will ever be able to help you with... You need to come up with something like a solid problem description. Also the whole code you pasted here is not really well written, in fact it's pretty bad (read about MVC). I have no idea and honestly no interest in debugging *this*. I can't even fit everything that is wrong with this code into the comment. Best advice is to start over and do the tutorials on book.cakephp.org.